# how to mock errorDecoder

Tags: junit, mockito, junit5

I have a class in my bff to decode errors from backend. Everything works fine, but I'm having trouble with unitTest in default case.

My class have some part to get the error, that is not relevant for the problem and a switch case to throw the required exception, the problem is the default case in it:

```
public class RetreiveMessageErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
private ErrorDecoder errorDecoder = new Default();

@Override
public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    // code to get the Error, not needed for the problem
    switch (response.status()) {
        case 500:
            return new GeneralInternalServerErrorException(error.getMessage());
        default:
            return errorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
    }
}
```

The test is:

```
ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

public class RetreiveMessageErrorDecoderTest {

```
private RetreiveMessageErrorDecoder retreiveMessageErrorDecoder;

@Mock
private Response response;
@Mock
private Response.Body body;


@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    retreiveMessageErrorDecoder = new RetreiveMessageErrorDecoder();
}

@Test
public void testDecodeDefault() throws IOException {
    Error error = new Error();
    error.setMessage("Default");
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(error));
    when(response.status()).thenReturn(400);
    when(response.body()).thenReturn(body);
    when(response.body().asInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
    ErrorDecoder errorDecoder = mock(ErrorDecoder.class);
    when(errorDecoder.decode(anyString(), any(Response.class))).thenReturn(new Exception("Default"));
    Exception exception = retreiveMessageErrorDecoder.decode("methodKey", response);
    assertEquals(Exception.class, exception.getClass());
    assertEquals("Default", exception.getMessage());
}
```

}

the problem seems to be the errorDecoder is not mocked properly and this line is not working (if I debug I see how the method is invoked):

```
        when(errorDecoder.decode(anyString(), any(Response.class))).thenReturn(new Exception("Default"));
```

what can be my error?